# SBT remote caching weird invalidation

Tags: scala, caching, sbt

meta info

```
sbt=1.8.0 jdk=Amazon.com Inc. Java 1.8.0_342
```

I created a simple project using `sbt new ...` with the following directory structure

```
.
├── main
│   └── scala
│       └── example
│           ├── A.scala
│           ├── B.scala
│           ├── C.scala
│           ├── D.scala
│           ├── E.scala
│           └── Hello.scala
└── test
    └── scala
        └── example
            └── HelloSpec.scala
```

build.sbt looks like

```
import Dependencies._

ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.13.8"
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization     := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"

ThisBuild / pushRemoteCacheTo := Some(MavenCache("local-cache", file("/tmp/cache")))
ThisBuild / logLevel := Level.Debug
ThisBuild / incOptions := incOptions.value.withApiDebug(true).withRelationsDebug(true)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "helloworldsbt",
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test
  )
```

I then performed a

```
sbt  "; compile; pushRemoteCache;"
```

The cache now looks like

```
[19:26:51] ➜  helloworldsbt cd  /tmp/cache/com/example/helloworldsbt_2.13
[19:27:59] ➜  helloworldsbt_2.13 tree
.
├── 0.0.0-55c7c2b9b2d9068c
│   ├── helloworldsbt_2.13-0.0.0-55c7c2b9b2d9068c-cached-test.jar
│   ├── helloworldsbt_2.13-0.0.0-55c7c2b9b2d9068c-cached-test.jar.md5
│   └── helloworldsbt_2.13-0.0.0-55c7c2b9b2d9068c-cached-test.jar.sha1
└── 0.0.0-f0c3847d849b0a58
    ├── helloworldsbt_2.13-0.0.0-f0c3847d849b0a58-cached-compile.jar
    ├── helloworldsbt_2.13-0.0.0-f0c3847d849b0a58-cached-compile.jar.md5
    └── helloworldsbt_2.13-0.0.0-f0c3847d849b0a58-cached-compile.jar.sha1
```

I then copied my project to some other subfolder ( with same name ) and updated just one file in the project

But on performing

```
sbt  "pullRemoteCache; compile;"
```

I get a full compilation

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.8.0 (Amazon.com Inc. Java 1.8.0_342)
[info] loading project definition from /Users/faiz.halde/p/helloworldsbt/project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to helloworldsbt (in build file:/Users/faiz.halde/p/helloworldsbt/)
[debug] not up to date. inChanged = true, force = false
[debug] Updating ...
[debug] Done updating
[debug] Other repositories:
[debug] Default repositories:
[debug] Using inline dependencies specified in Scala.
[debug]         tried file:/tmp/cache/com/example/helloworldsbt_2.13/0.0.0-a920b6ad175a9a8a/helloworldsbt_2.13-0.0.0-a920b6ad175a9a8a-cached-compile.jar
[info] remote cache artifact not found for com.example:helloworldsbt:0.0.0-a920b6ad175a9a8a Some(cached-compile)
[debug] failed to download Vector(com.example#helloworldsbt_2.13;0.0.0-a920b6ad175a9a8a!helloworldsbt_2.13.jar): local-cache
[debug] Using inline dependencies specified in Scala.
[debug]     [NOT REQUIRED] com.example#helloworldsbt_2.13;0.0.0-55c7c2b9b2d9068c!helloworldsbt_2.13.jar
[info] remote cache artifact extracted for com.example:helloworldsbt:0.0.0-55c7c2b9b2d9068c Some(cached-test)
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Dec 24, 2022 7:30:36 PM
[debug] [zinc] IncrementalCompile -----------
[debug] IncrementalCompile.incrementalCompile
[debug] previous = Stamps for: 0 products, 0 sources, 0 libraries
[debug] current source = Set(${BASE}/src/main/scala/example/D.scala, ${BASE}/src/main/scala/example/C.scala, ${BASE}/src/main/scala/example/B.scala, ${BASE}/src/main/scala/example/E.scala, ${BASE}/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala, ${BASE}/src/main/scala/example/A.scala)
[debug] > initialChanges = InitialChanges(Changes(added = Set(${BASE}/src/main/scala/example/C.scala, ${BASE}/src/main/scala/example/E.scala, ${BASE}/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala, ${BASE}/src/main/scala/example/D.scala, ${BASE}/src/main/scala/example/A.scala, ${BASE}/src/main/scala/example/B.scala), removed = Set(), changed = Set(), unmodified = ...),Set(),Set(),API Changes: Set())
[debug] Full compilation, no sources in previous analysis.
[debug] all 6 sources are invalidated
[debug] Created transactional ClassFileManager with tempDir = /Users/faiz.halde/p/helloworldsbt/target/scala-2.13/classes.bak
[debug] [inv] Invalidate package objects by inheritance only...
[debug] Initial set of included nodes:
[debug] [inv] Package object invalidations:
[debug] Recompiling all sources: number of invalidated sources > 50.0 percent of all sources
[debug] About to delete class files:
[debug] We backup class files:
[debug] [inv] ********* Pruned:
[debug] [inv] Relations:
[debug] [inv]   products: Relation [ ]
[debug] [inv]   library deps: Relation [ ]
[debug] [inv]   library class names: Relation [ ]
[debug] [inv]   internalDependencies:
[debug] [inv]   externalDependencies:
[debug] [inv]   class names: Relation [ ]
[debug] [inv]   used names: UsedNames [ ]
[debug] [inv]   product class names: Relation [ ]
[debug] [inv] *********
[debug] compilation cycle 1
[info] compiling 6 Scala sources to /Users/faiz.halde/p/helloworldsbt/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
```

Have I misunderstood the usage of remote caching?

```
Full compilation, no sources in previous analysis
```

Why isn't my remote cache not containing sources?